# Connecting to a server inside a DMZ

Tags: security, networking, dmz

in this scenario

```
           [ net2 / 10.0.1.1 ] ---- [ net1 / 10.0.0.1 ] --- ( Internet )
                    |                          |      
                 < pc2 >                    < pc1 >
```

if i set pc2 inside a DMZ would it be able to interact with pc1 and any other devices as if they where both connected to the same router ? Would pc2 be able to send broadcast packets and recieve them, access and serve all ports without NAT forwarding

I'm unable to test this and cant find any straight answers to this question

thanks

Comment: Since you talk about DMZ I guess there is a firewall involved. So it completely depends on what firewall rules you configure! By the way, you didn't give the prefix lengths for 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.0.1 so it's not clear whether or not they're on the same layer 3 network. The only part of your question I can answer is about the broadcasts: assuming pc1 and pc2 are on separate layer 3 networks, they cannot of course communicate using broadcast packets.

Comment: Well to be more specific about the scenario, and sorry for not doing so in my previous post, the two networks are just two interconnected Linksys routers with stock firmware. net2 bas the 10.0.1.255 range and net1 the 10.0.0.255 range. The idea is to have pc2 (a home server) freely interact with net1 without physically moving it

Comment: Say en1 is your server (static) and en2 is lan (NAT) you have two options. 1 set incoming rule/s from en2 to en1 on specific ports you need. 21, 80, 443... etc. or 2 create a vpn account for en2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on your subnetting router setup. For instance

```
         A: 10.0.0.0/24
    Subnet: 255.255.255.0
First host: 10.0.0.1
 Last host: 10.0.0.254
```

Total hosts: 254
     Broadcast: 10.0.0.255

If I'm thinking correctly they can't talk unless you bridge the subnets via a router.

If they are just hooked to a hub I believe PC2 can send packets to PC1's location, but PC1 can't respond back, but don't quote me on that one.